# How to run code when any object with the same name is touched

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to develop a small coin collecting game on Roblox, and am pretty new to scripting. Basically Every 0.25 - 1.5 seconds, a small part is cloned from `(-254, 2, -255)` (one corner of the baseplate), to `(254, 2, 255)` (the opposite corner). That works, but im trying to loop over every object in `workspace` named `coin`, and when one is touched, run code (for now im just trying to destroy the object but ill probably just update the `Coins` leaderstat). It doesn't give me any errors, it just doesnt work. I've also looked all over the internet, and cant find anything.

Code in `ServerScriptStorage` (spawns cubes and already works, but showed it for help.):

```lua
local runservice = game:GetService("RunService")
local interval = math.random(0.25, 1.5)
local coin = game.ServerStorage.coin
local counter = 0
local x = math.random(-254, 254)
local z = math.random(-255, 255)

runservice.Heartbeat:Connect(function(step)
    counter = counter + step
    if counter >= interval then
        counter = counter - interval
        local copy = coin:Clone()
        copy.Parent = workspace
        copy.Position = Vector3.new(x, 2, z)
        x = math.random(-254, 254)
        z = math.random(-255, 255)
        interval = math.random(0.25, 1.5)
    end
end)
```

script in desktop that handles the touching:

```lua
for _, v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if v.Name == "coin" then
        print("foo")
    end
end
```

I hope this is enough to help!

Comment: I suggest that you: 1) make sure that the `workspace` in the first code fragment is the same as in the second one, 2) make sure that the loop `for _, v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren())` is run at least once, 3) find out what `v` is in each iteration.

Comment: I don't really understand what this means or how to do it so please could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you are new to scripting in roblox let me give you your answer with good practices that may help you a lot.
First in this scenario you dont need to use Heartbeat, instead you could simple use a while loop or a recursive function and a simple wait().
Also you better create a "Coins" Folder in workspace in order to not check other objects

```
local waitTime = math.random(25,150)/100 --random time between 0.25 and 1.5
while true do  --forever loop
    wait(waitTime)   --waits desired time
    local coin = game.ServerStorage.coin:Clone() --cloning your coin
    coin.Parent = workspace.Coins --Coins folder
    coin.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(0,10),2,math.random(0,10)) --you must use your own position
    coin.Touched:Connect(function(hitPart) --here is the touched function
        local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(hitPart.Parent.Name) --check if the hitPart is part of a player
        if plr then 
            plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value =  plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value + 1--here you can increment your coins value in your own value
            coin:Destroy()--destroys the coin
        end
    end)
    waitTime = math.random(25,150)/100 --set a new random value to wait next
end
```

Also you mentioned something about loop every coin in workspace, thats why I said it is better to create a separate folder. So I made a localscript inside StarterPlayerScripts with the following code:

```
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService") --service
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function() --function on every game frame
    for i,v in pairs(workspace.Coins:GetChildren()) do --loop on every coin
        v.Orientation = Vector3.new(v.Orientation.X,v.Orientation.Y+5,v.Orientation.Z) --increasing Orientation just on Y in order to rotate them 
    end
end)
```

I'm doing this on localscript because is just a visual effect and it is never a good idea to send that many functions that quickly serverside. Here is the game I made for you:
https://www.roblox.com/games/5842250223/Help-for-TextBasedYoutube
You can edit the place.

In other words to answer "How to run code when any object with the same name is touched?"
You need to set the function for the object when creating it.

Edit: Also is not a good idea to send to many request to the server in short periods of time, I would recommend you to create a coin ever 2 to 3 seconds or more.

Comment: When I said "loop" i meant run code that loops over every coin, but, you answered it above. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how would you add add a bindable event to this so that you use that to increase the coins? I want to do that because I'm going to add DataStore2 to it. Actually nvm, just managed to get  it working.

Comment: Getting DS2 working wasnt too hard with the code you gave, so Thanks again!